# Unix reading variables from a file after specific text

Tags: unix

I am trying to read variables from a file with some text as argument.

```
my file looks like this

[INTERFACE1]
output_path=/some/outputpath/
input_path=/some/inputpath/

[INTERFACE2]
output_path=/some/outputpath/
input_path=/some/inputpath
```

so from the above file I want to read output path and input path as variables by passing INTERFACE1 or INTERFACE2 as argument to my script

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat /tmp/vars.ini 
[INTERFACE1]
output_path=/some/outputpath/
input_path=/some/inputpath/

[INTERFACE2]
output_path=/some/outputpath/
input_path=/some/inputpath
$ awk '/\[INTERFACE2\]/,/^$/' /tmp/vars.ini # assumes that sections are seperated by blank lines
[INTERFACE2]
output_path=/some/outputpath/
input_path=/some/inputpath
$ awk '/\[INTERFACE2\]/,/^$/' /tmp/vars.ini  | sed 1d
output_path=/some/outputpath/
input_path=/some/inputpath
$ source <(awk '/\[INTERFACE2\]/,/^$/' /tmp/vars.ini  | sed 1d) # if your shell supports <()
$ echo $input_path 
/some/inputpath
```